# Why am I getting java.lang.VerifyError when enhancing ebean scala entity

Tags: java, scala, akka, ebean

I am new to ebean and scala/akka and am trying to persist a minimal case class as an ebean entity.  My dependencies are as follows:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.9",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.3.9",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % "2.3.9",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.9" % "test",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.0.0",
  "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.18",
  "org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "4.7.1",
  "org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm-agent" % "4.5.3",
  "org.avaje" % "avaje-agentloader" % "1.1.3",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-pool2" % "2.0")
```

and my entity:

```
package zw.co.esol.eswitch.model

import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import com.avaje.ebean.Model

@Entity
case class Test(@Id id: Long, firstname: String) extends Model
```

and my main:

```
object ApplicationMain extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("eswitch", ConfigFactory.load())

  //system.logConfiguration()

    // Load the agent into the running JVM process
    if (!AgentLoader.loadAgentFromClasspath("avaje-ebeanorm-agent","debug=1;packages=zw.co.esol.eswitch.model.*")) {
      println("avaje-ebeanorm-agent not found in classpath - not dynamically loaded");
    }

    EbeanDbServer.init
    //more code follows.......
```

and my ebean init code:

```
object EbeanDbServer {

  def init = {

    // programmatically build a EbeanServer instance  
    // specify the configuration...  

    println("@@ Starting EbeanServer...")

    var config = new ServerConfig();  
    config.setName("pgtest");  

    // Define DataSource parameters  
    var postgresDb = new DataSourceConfig();  
    postgresDb.setDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    postgresDb.setUsername("user");  
    postgresDb.setPassword("password");  
    postgresDb.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/eswitch");  
    postgresDb.setHeartbeatSql("select count(*) from message");  

    config.setDataSourceConfig(postgresDb);  

    // specify a JNDI DataSource   
    // config.setDataSourceJndiName("someJndiDataSourceName");  

    // set DDL options...  
    config.setDdlGenerate(false);  
    config.setDdlRun(false);  

    config.setDefaultServer(false);  
    config.setRegister(false);  

    var test = Test(1, "stan")
    // automatically determine the DatabasePlatform  
    // using the jdbc driver   
    // config.setDatabasePlatform(new PostgresPlatform());  

    // specify the entity classes (and listeners etc)  
    // ... if these are not specified Ebean will search  
    // ... the classpath looking for entity classes.  

      config.addClass(classOf[Test]);  

    // specify jars to search for entity beans  
 //   config.addJar("someJarThatContainsEntityBeans.jar");  

    // create the EbeanServer instance  
    val server: EbeanServer = EbeanServerFactory.create(config);

    println("@@ EbeanServer started... : " + server.getName)

  }
}
```

But I get the output when running the app:

```
ebean-enhance> cls: zw/co/esol/eswitch/model/Test  msg: ... skipping add equals() ... already has equals() hashcode() methods
ebean-enhance> cls: zw/co/esol/eswitch/model/Test  msg: enhanced 
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
[error] Exception Details:
[error]   Location:
[error]     zw/co/esol/eswitch/model/Test.<init>(JLjava/lang/String;)V @2: invokevirtual
[error]   Reason:
[error]     Type uninitializedThis (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'zw/co/esol/eswitch/model/Test'
[error]   Current Frame:
[error]     bci: @2
[error]     flags: { flagThisUninit }
[error]     locals: { uninitializedThis, long, long_2nd, 'java/lang/String' }
[error]     stack: { uninitializedThis, long, long_2nd }
[error]   Bytecode:
[error]     0000000: 2a1f b600 932a 2db6 0096 2ab7 0099 2abb
[error]     0000010: 009b 592a b700 9eb5 00a0 2ab8 00a6 b1  
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    zw/co/esol/eswitch/model/Test.<init>(JLjava/lang/String;)V @2: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type uninitializedThis (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'zw/co/esol/eswitch/model/Test'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @2
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis, long, long_2nd, 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { uninitializedThis, long, long_2nd }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a1f b600 932a 2db6 0096 2ab7 0099 2abb
    0000010: 009b 592a b700 9eb5 00a0 2ab8 00a6 b1  

        at zw.co.esol.eswitch.database.EbeanDbServer$.init(EbeanDbServer.scala:45)
        at zw.co.esol.eswitch.global.ApplicationMain$.delayedEndpoint$zw$co$esol$eswitch$global$ApplicationMain$1(ApplicationMain.scala:28)
        at zw.co.esol.eswitch.global.ApplicationMain$delayedInit$body.apply(ApplicationMain.scala:17)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at zw.co.esol.eswitch.global.ApplicationMain$.main(ApplicationMain.scala:17)
        at zw.co.esol.eswitch.global.ApplicationMain.main(ApplicationMain.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

I am using java version "1.7.0_55" on Linux x86_64.

What could I be doing wrong? I have tried to search for a solution but all the threads I have seen so far are not helping.

Comment: Have you found any solution? If so can u share with me?

Answer (score 1):

For some folks who might be facing this error using ebean without playframework

In your model if you are returning a POJO class in any function and if this error occurs while running your unit test case or other scenario then add setter and getter methods in your POJO class or any unrelated model class and use those functions to deal with it. dont directly access member variables and manipulate them. that produces this error. when i generated all getter/setter it resolved issue for me